# Alternative to { } in Swift? Having trouble formatting the parameters for API request

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to format the data to send in with a URLSESSION POST API request and I'm getting an error.

**This is the format of the data that should sent in (python):**

```
values = """
  {
    "CatalogID": 79295989,
    "ItemQuantity": 74216946.47779638,
    "ItemOptions": [
      {
        "OptionSetID": 15820261,
        "OptionID": 47597762,
        "OptionValue": "dolore fugiat"
      },
      {
        "OptionSetID": 99572501,
        "OptionID": 91126905,
        "OptionValue": "deserunt"
      }
    ]
  }
```

So far this is what I have. Instead of using curly braces I used braces to try to create lists of OptionSet/ID/Value inside ItemOptions. Unfortunately this isn't working and returns an error from the server.

Is there a proper way to format this in Swift since OptionSetID/ID/Value appear multiple times and have the same name? Does Swift have an alternative to the curly braces shown to separate each list of OptionSetID/ID/Value above?

```
parameters:
[
    "CatalogID": 1877,
    "ItemQuantity": 1,
    "ItemOptions":
        [
            [ "OptionSetID": 3489,
              "OptionID": 93171,
              "OptionValue": 0],
            [ "OptionSetID": 3491,
              "OptionID": 93192,
              "OptionValue": 2.16],
            [ "OptionSetID": 3492,
              "OptionID": 93579,
              "OptionValue": 0]
    ]
]
```

Comment: You need to send JSON. You can create an create some structs And use `Codable`

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more on this? How would this work if there are multiple OptionSetID's and they all are called OptionSetID? I've also used the above dictionary request without lists for other API requests and those seem to have worked so is it necessary to create new structs with Codable?

Comment: You don't have to use `Codable`, but your code will be much more readable and maintainable if you do. If you dolt, then `ItemOptions` is simply an array of dictionaries.  Each element in the array is a separate dictionary, so the repeated key names aren't a problem

Comment: BTW, the approach you have shown in your question is correct. what error is the server giving you?

Comment: It's not so much an error from Swift, but it's an error from the API. It returns an error code and says that CatalogID is not a valid number. I feel like the issue isn't with CatalogID but rather with the formatting of ItemOptions. I tried sending an identical request with the same values through the API's testing tool and it worked, which is why I'm keen on the formatting being the issue.

Comment: I understood that it was a server error, but you need to look at what that error is telling you.  Using `Codable` rather than hand-coding JSON is typically a better approach because you reduce manual coding

Comment: I just ran it again and it verbatim gave me "CatalogID is not valid." I'm not sure how much more I can get out of that error message.

I'm open to doing it with Codable, but I'd like to try it with hand-coding JSON since this is one of the only instances where I'll need this.

Comment: What you show in your question is the correct hand-coded structure that is equivalent to the JSON you show at the top.  You can use that structure with the older [JSONSerializtion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization/1413636-data) class to get JSON.  My reading of the error message you are getting from the server is that the value you are specifying for `CatalogID` isn't a valid value.  Nothing to do with the structure.

Comment: I used the same variables values and sent them in to the API Testing playground and it gives me a success message. I've also double checked the types and they seem to be correct as well, which is why I don't understand why the error is giving me a CatalogID error. 

My best guess is the error messages from the API could be inaccurate, but other than that I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: I am using JSONSerialization to put my parameters into JSON format as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send JSON.  One way to do this is to model your data with structs and use `Codable` and `JSONEncoder`

```
struct CatalogItem: Codable {
    var catalogId: Int
    var itemQuantity: Float
    var itemOptions: [ItemOption]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case catalogId = "CatalogID"
       case itemQuantity = "ItemQuantity"
       case itemOptions = "ItemOptions"
    }
}

struct ItemOption: Codable {
    var optionSetId: Int
    var optionId: Int
    var optionValue: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case optionSetId = "OptionSetID"
       case optionId = "OptionID"
       case optionValue = "OptionValue"
    }
}
```

You then create an instance of `CatalogItem`, adding `ItemOptions` to it as required and convert it JSON data:

```
var catalogItem = CatalogItem(catalogId: 1877, itemQuantity: 74216946.47779638, itemOptions:
        [ ItemOption(optionSetId: 15820261, optionId: 47597762, optionValue: "dolore fugiat"),  
          ItemOption(optionSetId: 99572501, optionId: 91126905, optionValue: "deserunt")
         ])
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(catalogItem)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(jsonString)
catch {
    print(error)
}
```